# PHP, getting blank site when doing INSERT into database.table

Tags: php, insert

I just want to say that chances are it's going to be something fairly simple here.

I'm working on a site where the user basically fills in a form with some data which on submit gets sent (GET) to another php-page that includes my db-connection script right under the header, and then goes on to perform an SQL query in form of an INSERT. This page just shows on blank. I have some html elements that's supposed to show up if there is no mysql_error().

Here is how the page looks like, what am I doing wrong here?

```
           <?php                                                                          
          include '/partials/header.php';                                              
          include '/functions/db_connection.php';                                      

           if(isset($_POST['value0'])) {                                                

            $value0 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value0"]);                        
            $value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value1"]);                  
            $value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value2"]);                
            $value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value3"]);                  
            $value4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value4"]);                        
            $value5 = date("d-m-Y");                                                     

            $query = "INSERT INTO db.my_table(value0, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7) 
                      VALUES ('. $value0 .',                                        
                                '. $value1 .',                                       
                                '. $value2 .',                                       
                                '. $value3 .', 
                                '. $value4 .',                                          
                                '. $value5 .',                                          
                                'enum-value', 
                                '. $value7 .');";                                        

              $result = mysql_query($query);                                           

              if(!$result)                                                             
              {
                //something went wrong, display the error                              
                echo 'Congratulations, something went wrong. You are officially retarded.<br /><br />' . mysql_error();
                $sql = "ROLLBACK;";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);                                           
              } 
              else
              {                                                                        
                $sql = "COMMIT;";                                                      
                $result = mysql_query($sql);                                           
        ?>      

          <div class="box">                                                            
            <h1 class="green">That's it!</h1>                                       
            <p>Let's do some more novice php scripting.</p>

          </div>

        <?php
      }
    }
?>
```

And here's my connection file:

```
    <?php
    $server = "servername";
    $userName = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $db = "db";       

    $con = mysql_connect($server,$userName,$password,$db);  

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

?>
```

Comment: You're using `mysql_connect`, and then `mysqli_connect_errno` - you can't mix mysql_* with mysqli_* like that

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors", true); right below the <?php and refresh

Comment: Don't end your sql queries with semi-colon `;`

Comment: what @exampleusername said... or look in your php_errors log file for the error that is begin raised.

Answer (score 2):

You've got bad quoting or at least bad concatenation on your string...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO yada yada
          VALUES ('. $value0 .', 
                  ^---
```

you've started a double-quoted string, so the variables don't need to be "concatenated" into the string. e.g. `$x = "hello $there how are you"` will work fine. So either switch to double-quotes throughout:

```
  VALUES ('" . $value0 . "' ...
           ^--           ^--
```

or simply eliminate the attempt at concatenation:

```
  VALUES('$value0', ....
```

Answer (score 0):

change this block of code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO db.my_table(value0, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7) 
          VALUES ('. $value0 .',                                        
                    '. $value1 .',                                       
                    '. $value2 .',                                       
                    '. $value3 .', 
                    '. $value4 .',                                          
                    '. $value5 .',                                          
                    'enum-value', 
                    '. $value7 .');";
```

to this one

```
$query = "INSERT INTO db.my_table(value0, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7) 
          VALUES ('. $value0 .',                                        
                    '. $value1 .',                                       
                    '. $value2 .',                                       
                    '. $value3 .', 
                    '. $value4 .',                                          
                    '. $value5 .',                                          
                    'enum-value', 
                    '. $value7 .')";
```

Comment: Thank you all, I've realised I have some cathcing up to do regarding PHP versions and the new ways of doing things. Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO db.my_table(value0, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7) 
              VALUES ('". $value0 ."',                                        
                        '". $value1 ."',                                       
                        '". $value2 ."',                                       
                        '". $value3 ."', 
                        '". $value4 ."',                                          
                        '". $value5 ."',                                          
                        'enum-value', 
                        '". $value7 ."')";
```

Quotes were done wrong in the query. See above. You should be using ".." to step into the variable realm, not '. - as your string was started using ".